# Problem with Big O notation

Tags: real-analysis

1) True or False? Prove your Answer

a) $O(2^n)= O(n^n)$
False, because $\forall n \ge 3 : 2^n<n^n$

b) $2^n = O(n^n)$
True, because $\forall n \ge2: 2^n< 1.n^n$

c) $O(2^n) = O(2^{2n})$
False, because $\forall n \ge 1: 2^n < 2^{2n}$

My explanations are really short, but do you think it is enough?

Comment: Note that it is possible to have $O(f(n))=O(g(n))$ and at the same time $O(g(n))\ne O(f(n))$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Impossible, I think. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for each case you have, take the limit of the ratio. What do you get? Not that if $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to_n 0 $ this means that $a_n = o(b_n)$, which is a better estimate than $O(b_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation refers the asymptotic limit of time complexity, and the easiest way to compare them is to assume that $n$ is large enough to ignore constants, and ask what is the running time difference between inputs sized $n$ and $2n$.  Thus $\mathcal O(f) = \mathcal O(g)$ only if $\tfrac{f(2n)}{f(n)} = \tfrac{g(2n)}{g(n)}$

Comment: No. $O(n) = O(n + 1)$, but $\frac {2n} n  \ne \frac {2 n + 1} {n + 1}$.